# View Azure portal AAD sign-in logs and activity audit logs in 1 single view for multiple subscriptions

Tags: azure-active-directory

When having multiple Azure subscriptions, can we view Azure portal [AAD sign-in logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-sign-ins)   and [activity audit logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs) in 1 single view, instead of per Azure subscription? If yes, how? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the [sign-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-sign-ins#prerequisites) and [audit-logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs#who-can-access-the-data) require the limited user roles to access them, and the sign-ins requires the Azure AD License that must have an Azure AD Premium license. But all of them have no requirements to display their activities with the Azure Subscriptions. For this, you could directly see from the columns in the audit-logs and sign-ins.

[image]

Comment: @PYK, if there is anything update, please let me know, thanks.